# React not picking up environment variables (create-react-app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to access the environment variables in my React App, however they aren't registering.

```js
console.log(process.env)
```

[image]

All of my variables are in a file named `.env.development.local`, and are prefixed with `REACT_APP_`

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY_IF=XXXX
REACT_APP_API_KEY_MAPFLIGHT=XXXX
REACT_APP_SESSION_ID=XXXX
```

What could I be doing wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so it looks like I was supposed to restart the server after adding new Variables, that did it.